# Azure IoT hub - reducing data down/upload

Tags: c#, azure, iot, azure-iot-hub

I am working with Azure IoT hub and have a test environment running at the moment. However we are using 4g data subscriptions (Mobile) to upload measurements from our devices and I have done a lot to reduce the data that we gather and upload every 10 minutes. However when measuring the data consumption I still see quite a big overhead. My data take up around 300 bytes compressed, but after measuring data with NetBalancer I can see that after 1 day my application have sent 1.2 MB and received 2.3 MB. I am using the MQTT protocol as that should have the smallest footprint.

I can't seem to find any best practice or similar to reduce the data sent on the wire using IoT hub. Any help is highly appreciated! :)

Comment: You might want to look into determining the [packet loss](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packet_loss) of the connection since this will cause data to be retransmitted.

Comment: You absolutely sure the RX/TX size you're measuring is JUST the MQTT traffic? Is your MQTT client a Windows PC? There's a lot of chattery going on to/from Internet with Windows even when Windows Update is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to reduce the size of the message by serializing using **[Protocol Buffers](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/)** (there are nuget packages available for C#).

Take a look at the [Serialize telemetry using Protocol Buffers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-accelerators/iot-accelerators-device-simulation-protobuf) guide, on how you might be able to implement it.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Here are some things you can try:

1. If you are disconnecting after each message, avoid doing so. A TLS handshake can cost up to 10 Kilobytes whereas keep alive pings cost only 80 bytes sent every minute. Reconnecting after every message is often not  economical.
2. Avoid TLS altogether and use a protocol gateway between the client and IoTHub as a TLS termination point. (This is risky but if you can encrypt your payload in some other reliable way, can prove to be a viable option)
3. As suggested by Itay, try alternate serialisation options such as protocol buffers or flatbuffers. These tend to have much smaller footprints than JSON
4. Make sure you're using the best compression algorithm for your payload.

It helps to create a simulator on your local network and monitor the traffic using a packet capture tool such as Wireshark to find the source of the problem.